# Exercise and Yoga Asana after Eating

Tags: exercise, yoga

What are some exercises and/or yoga asana, that I can practice after eating to avoid sleepiness and to maintain my concentration and motivation toward work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several yoga asanas that you can practice:

- Cat-cow pose (Marjaryasana-Bitilasana): This pose involves alternating between arching your back and rounding your spine, which can help to improve your posture and increase blood flow to the brain.
- Forward bend (Uttanasana): This pose involves bending forward from the waist, which can help to stretch the back and legs and improve your circulation.
- Triangle pose (Trikonasana): This pose involves stretching the sides of the body, which can help to improve your balance and focus.
- Child's pose (Balasana): This pose involves stretching the back and hips, which can help to calm the mind and improve your focus.
- Seated forward bend (Paschimottanasana): This pose involves stretching the back and legs, which can help to improve your concentration and focus.

As for excercises, just the most obvious:

- Walking: Taking a brief walk can help to increase your blood flow and improve your focus and concentration.
- Stretching: Simple stretches, such as reaching your arms overhead or stretching your legs, can help to improve your circulation and wake up your body.